# The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([id]), true]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where() field parameter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**Firestore flutter giving Error when performing Orderby and Query Together**

I don't know its the package or query. when

```
      body: PaginateFirestore(
        itemBuilderType: PaginateBuilderType.listView,
        itemBuilder: (index, context, documentSnapshot) {
          final data = documentSnapshot.data() as Map?;
          // final sub = data.
          return InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.person)),
              title: data == null ? Text('Error in data') : Text(data['id']),
            ),
          );
        },
        // orderBy is compulsory to enable pagination
        query: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Phones').where('price',isGreaterThan:'560' ).orderBy('id',descending: true),
        // to fetch real-time data
        isLive: true,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Error While running code

```
    The following assertion was thrown building Retrive(dirty):
The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([id]), true]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([price])" when an inequality operator is invoked.
'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart':
Failed assertion: line 484 pos 13: 'conditionField == orders[0][0]'
```

Comment: Yup, that limitation is listed here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations

Comment: So is it string = string scene or field = field to read + query + orderby

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand that comment at all. (But fundamentally, you're trying to filter by one field and sort by another, and that isn't supported.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([id]), true]][0][0]" has to
> be the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([price])" when
> an inequality operator is invoked.

This means the first `orderBy` has to be the field you did the inequality query on, that is, `price`.

- Update your query from:

```
query: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Phones').where('price',isGreaterThan:'560' ).orderBy('id',descending: true)
```

to:

```
query: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Phones').where('price',isGreaterThan:'560' ).orderBy('price').orderBy('id',descending: true)
```

- Run this query and you'll get a message on the console, together with a link, that says you need to create an [index](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/index-overview).
- Click on the link and create the index.
- Wait for the index to complete the creation process and run the query again.

Comment: Can you please check out my question if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68351097/reading-firebase-storage-image-security-rules